# How to get BlueSky Stat to add a random number to a variable value

Tags: r

I am using BlueSky Statistics v10. I have a need to compute a new variable from an existying one we'll call Rating. I would like to create a new variable, NewRating, that has the value of Rating+RandomNumber. The random number needs to be very small.

I do this in Excel by creating a new column, labeling it NewRating, and using the formula "=Rating+0.0001 * rand(). This gives me the exact output I need. Note: Rating refers to the cell with the Rating, such as H2. I'd like to do replicate this in BlueSky for reasons of efficiency and data accuracy.

Many thanks in advance for considering my question and helping me out. I am a newbie, don't know R, and use the menus exclusively.

What I've done so far: I tried to calculate a new variable from an existing one, using the value of the existing variable, then adding 0.0001 to it, and then tried to add a random number using the variables:compute menu item. It failed.

Comment: Is BlueSky Statistics an open source product? Is it a menu driven facade for R in the same fashion as John Fox's Rcmdr? Can you offer links to the product and its documentation?

Comment: Looks that way: https://www.blueskystatistics.com/

Comment: Are there any BlueSky forums you could ask on?  The overlap between people who hang out answering R questions on SO and people who are familiar with BlueSky is probably pretty small ...

Comment: PS: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=BlueSky+Statistics